µBlock: How to Add a CSS-class in a Filter?
µBlock (uBlock) provides action operator :remove-class(), but how can I add a CSS-class?
On a site an element alternates between two CSS-classes. I have a rule with :remove-class() that is triggered every now and then, but then the page looks weird. Therefore, I want to remove one class as I do now, but also add the other CSS-class.
example.com##.ad_wrapper:watch-attr(class):remove-class(ad_wrapper-visible)
!how to add class "ad_wrapper-hidden"?


I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a specific web application. It's about installable software (a web browser extension). Questions about installable software might be on-topic in [su].

@Rubén-VolunteerModerator- Wouldn't this count as "Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)"?

@Laurel The question does not ask how to use a web browser extension feature directly related to using a web application.

@Rubén-VolunteerModerator- Which site would be best for this question?

@sjngm Please ask for a SE site recommendation in [meta.se].

@sjngm Laurel try https://superuser.com
